# Canvas separates image into sections upon scaling

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm animating a few photos about and when I try to scale disproportionately on this canvas, it does something very peculiar...

[image: This is wrong]

`ctx1.drawImage(img1,0,0,w,h);` works fine, but `ctx1.drawImage(img1,0,0,w+100,h+100);` will give me this very strange effect. Any clue why, or how to stop it?

Comment: Just tested this in FireFox, this seems to only happen in Chrome. How odd!

Comment: Can you share your code on jsfiddle. so that I can see it.

Comment: @spankajd Its a bit too long for that, but trust me, the issue lies in the two lines I posted. And only in Chrome.

Comment: above two lines doesn't have any issue. 
issue might be happening due to other code for sure that is why I was asking for code. Without it nobody will figure out the issue.

Comment: @spankajd I am almost certain there is nothing wrong with my script. I was wondering if there was a bug in Chrome or something, or if it simply stemmed from the fact that disproportionate scaling causes issues like this.

Comment: What do you mean by `try to scale disproportionately on this canvas` ?

Comment: @Dummy I mean scale without keeping aspect ratio

Comment: If these two lines were really only what is needed, then it should be quite easy to make an [MCVE]. Do you see the bug in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye5phsvb/) ? Also, could you check the EXIF data of your image ? Does it have an `orientation` value ? I noticed chrome had a bug relative to this and drawing through canvas (basically it takes the width and height values of un-rotated image, but draws the rotated one, or the inverse I don't quite remember)